# Filter fields in Angular 2 based on timestamp compared with current time

Tags: angular, angular-template

I am building an application that shows a list of objects. Each object has an `archived_until` attribute that can hold the value *null* or a timestamp without time zone (for example: *2016-11-26 08:00:00.561139*).

I am trying to show a list of all these objects, and give the user the possibility to Toggle a button called `Show archived objects`. I was wondering what would be the best approach to compare a timestamp in Angular 2 with the current date? Can I get this working in the template or should I write a function in my component?

This is what I tried so far, it doesn't return any errors but is also doesn't filter as expected (it shows nothing). I added a butten that toggles the value of `show_archived_notes`:

```
<tr *ngFor="let notification of notifications">
    <ng-container 
     *ngIf=(!show_archived_notes && !notification.archived_until) || 
     notification.archived_until > currentDate>
        <td>Some attribute</td><td>Another attribute</td>...
    </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Where I initialized `currentDate` in my component as follows:

```
current_date = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simpler approach, write a pipe to filter archived and add an active param:

```
<tr *ngFor="let notification of notifications | archivePipe:show_archived_notes">
```

The pipe will get and array, if the active is false, return the array as is, if not, filter it by your logic.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'archivePipe'
})
export class ArchivePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(notes: Array<Notes>, active: boolean): Array<Notes> {
      if(active){
          return notes.filter(<your archive filter logic>);
      } else {
          return notes;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach! Do you have a suggestion what would be the proper syntax to compare a timestamp with the current date?

Comment: let now = Date.now(); and in your filter Date.parse(dateString) < now;